# Why not accounting for a factor unrelated to treatment makes p-values too conservative?

Tags: multilevel-analysis, group-differences, ancova, confounding, clustered-standard-errors

I would like to know if a treatment works, but different subjects are measured across different sites. The site is unrelated to treatment, but it is related to the response (see the figure).
[image]

If I put site indicators to the model, p-values are uniformly distributed between 0-1 as expected. However, If I don't account for a site, I would expect that the p-values would be overly optimistic because I am not accounting for the dependence in the data, however when I simulate this dataset many times, I see that p-values are actually too conservative, so to get p < 0.05 is much less likely than a 5% (see fig 2). Why is that?

[image]

```
n_sims <- 25000 #this takes a minute

results <- data.frame(p_values = rep(NA, n_sims))
for(i in 1:n_sims){
  # create site effects, unrelated to treatment, but related to response
  site_effects <- data.frame(site_id = LETTERS,
                             site_effects = seq(-1, 1, length.out = 26))
  df <- data.frame(site_id = as.factor(rep(LETTERS, 50)))
  df <- merge(df, site_effects)
  # treatment is unrelated to response and site
  df$treatment <- as.factor(c('yes', 'no'))
  # response related to site, but not treatment
  df$response <- rnorm(nrow(df), mean=df$site_effects, sd = 1)
  # save the p-value for treatment
  results[i,] <- summary(lm(response ~ treatment, data=df))$coefficients[2,'Pr(>|t|)']
}

# making plots
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(results, aes(x=p_values)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.01, boundary=0) +
  ggtitle("Histogram of p-values")

p2 <- ggplot(results, aes(sample=p_values)) +
  geom_qq(distribution = qunif) +
  stat_qq_line(distribution = qunif, color='red') +
  coord_fixed() +
  ggtitle("qq plot of p-values")
```

Answer (score 0):

As you (perhaps presciently) noted in your tags, this has to do with the type of standard errors used. The outcomes within a site are not independent, which means the standard OLS estimated standard errors will not be correct. Using cluster-robust standard errors (i.e., `sandwich::vcovCL(., cluster = ~site_id)`) produces the correct distribution of p-values, as shown in the plot below.

[image]

To get this plot, I replaced

```
results[i,] <- summary(lm(response ~ treatment, data=df))$coefficients[2,'Pr(>|t|)']
```

with

```
results[i,] <- lmtest::coeftest(lm(response ~ treatment, data=df), 
                                vcov. = sandwich::vcovCL, cluster = ~site_id)[2,'Pr(>|t|)']
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But why does it make p-values conservative and not optimistic? Which is what I would expect from dependent data.